# mobile app and push freeze in vaadin touchkit

Tags: cordova, gwt, phonegap-build, vaadin7, vaadin-touchkit

I tried to integrate Vaadin with Phonegap/Cordova.
I follow the instructions in this [repository](https://github.com/manolo/vaadin-touchkit-phonegap-cordova-start).
The problem is that the application freeze when I pause the phone.

Tomcat log when I turn off the screen in my android phone:

```
AVVERTENZA: Duplicate resource 782acdbe-068d-4405-a215-5770fd14086b. Could be caused by a dead connection not detected by your server. Replacing the old one with the fresh one
giu 01, 2016 5:51:53 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster addAtmosphereResource
AVVERTENZA: Duplicate resource 782acdbe-068d-4405-a215-5770fd14086b. Could be caused by a dead connection not detected by your server. Replacing the old one with the fresh one
giu 01, 2016 5:51:53 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster addAtmosphereResource
AVVERTENZA: Duplicate resource 782acdbe-068d-4405-a215-5770fd14086b. Could be caused by a dead connection not detected by your server. Replacing the old one with the fresh one
giu 01, 2016 5:51:53 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster addAtmosphereResource
AVVERTENZA: Duplicate resource 782acdbe-068d-4405-a215-5770fd14086b. Could be caused by a dead connection not detected by your server. Replacing the old one with the fresh one
```

I presume that the problem is with the push technology, I use long polling, but the problem is the same when I switch to `WebSocket`.
This is the JS console output.

[image: output console]

Any help on this? Anyone has the same experience?

Comment: Which version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: my version of Vaadin is 7.5.10

Comment: Try the latest stable. Push has fundamental changes in Vaadin 7.6